# items in array, take enum and cast as int to add up

Tags: c#, casting, enums, boolean

Another classic card/poker game issue; I am filling two hands with random cards (user, computer). For now we are just comparing the two hands and adding up the enum/rank value of the hands and comparing it. I have it displaying correctly, and I think I have the logic correct, but I'm just not understanding casting very well, especially when it comes to enums. Rank is established in an enum (deuce = 2, etc). SuperCard parent class has get set property of the rank as cardsRank

heres the SuperCard class:

```
public abstract class SuperCard
{
    #region Properties

    public Rank cardsRank { get; set; }
    public abstract Suit cardSuit { get; }

    #endregion

    public abstract void Draw();
}
```

Here's the main program:

```
CardLibrary.CardSet myDeck = new CardLibrary.CardSet(); // create deck of 52 cards
int howManyCards = 5;
int balance = 10;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;

Console.WriteLine("Welcome to NewPoker! \nYou get $10 to start. Each bet is $1"); // intro and rules

while (balance != 0)
{
    SuperCard[] computerHand = myDeck.GetCards(howManyCards); // create two hands, user/comp
    SuperCard[] myHand = myDeck.GetCards(howManyCards);
    DrawHands(computerHand, myHand); // call hands
    Console.ReadLine();
    bool won = CompareHands(computerHand, myHand);
    if (won)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You win this hand! Your balance is {0}", balance.ToString("C"));
        balance++;
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to play the next hand");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    if (!won)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The dealer wins this hand! Your balance is {0}", balance.ToString("C"));
        balance--;
        if (balance > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to play the next hand");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the CompareHands method:

```
public bool CompareHands(SuperCard[] compHand, SuperCard[] userHand)
{
    int compTotal = 0, userTotal = 0;
    foreach (var item in compHand)
    {
        //cast enum rank to int, add?
    }
    foreach (var item in userHand)
    {
        //cast enum rank to int, add?
    }
    if (userTotal > compTotal)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

in my mind I am thinking it would take a `foreach` loop to cycle each one, cast `item.cardsRank` (get set property in SuperClass for the `Rank` enum) to an int (which im not sure how), then add that value to a running total (`userTotal`, `compTotal`), then compare them for the return value as we are calling the bool in the program "won". any tips or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Enum underlying type". Basically, you specify values that can represent your enum values.

You can use any integral constants. For all C# integral types navigate to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The default is `int` so when you say

```
public enum Rank 
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

compiler sees it as

```
public enum Rank : int
{
    Value1 = 0,
    Value2 = 1
}
```

By default, it start from 0 for the first item and increments in order by one. But you don't have to abide by it. You don't event have to set any value to 0. When you need to get an underlying value from the code, just call

```
int rank = (int)Rank.Value1;
```

and replace `(int)` with the type you are using. You can also do it backwards.

```
Rank rank = (Rank)1;
```

but bear in mind that

> It is possible to assign any arbitrary integer value to rank. For example, this line of code does not produce an error: rank = (Rank) 42. However, you should not do this because the implicit expectation is that an enum variable will only hold one of the values defined by the enum. To assign an arbitrary value to a variable of an enumeration type is to introduce a high risk for errors. *From MSDN*.

Comment: while I didn't do this exactly the same, this helped me understand how I wanted to do it and got it figured out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do to get int value is cast.

```
void Main()
{
var rank = Rank.Two;
Console.Write((int)rank);
}

public enum Rank
{
None,
One = 1,
Two = 2
}
```

For example this will print 2.  The enum will init to zero, so I would stick a "none" value there.